# Tag merge request: 'organic' and 'biofood'

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I recently noticed the tag 'biofood', and was somewhat confused by this, until I came to the conclusion, based on [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/6718/4020), that it is another term for what, at least in the U.S., we call "organic food".

Based on this, I wonder if the two tags ought to be merged.  There are a very small number of questions with the [biofood](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biofood) tag, but I would hate to simply edit them to change the tag to [organic](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic)... that seems too U.S.-centric for such an international site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve never heard “biofood” in English usage (it’s used in other languages though), only “organic”. It’s certainly not US-centric.

Consequently I’ve moved the [biofood](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biofood) tag.